# IPMI password authentication

Tags: ipmitool, ipmi

I don't see the option of PASSWORD authentication at my IPMI channel 1 settings output. I even tried factory reset. Can you please let me know how I can enable the password authentication.

```
$ipmitool lan print 1

Auth Type Support       : MD2 MD5 OEM 
Auth Type Enable        : Callback : MD2 MD5 OEM 
                        : User     : MD2 MD5 OEM 
                        : Operator : MD2 MD5 OEM 
                        : Admin    : MD2 MD5 OEM 
                        : OEM      :
```

Answer (score 0):

Your IPMI device does not support the password authentication. The following line in the ipmitool output lists all of authentication types that are supported in your device:

```
Auth Type Support       : MD2 MD5 OEM
```

So authentication types `NONE` and `PASSWORD` are not supported. It is probably due to security reasons because both of them are rather bad choice for authentication. Nevertheless it is up to BMC firmware developer what authentication type is supported.

You can enable / disable authentication types that are supported by your device by ipmitool:

```
# ipmitool lan set 1 auth User NONE
# ipmitool lan print 1
...
Auth Type Support       : NONE MD5
Auth Type Enable        : Callback : MD5
                        : User     : NONE
                        : Operator : MD5
                        : Admin    : MD5
                        : OEM      : MD5
...
```

But I cannot set `PASSWORD` or `MD2` because they are not supported in my device.